# Adding pre-processor macros in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add pr-processor macros to my Xcode project. This project shares both Swift  and Objective-C code, so I cannot use `Swift Compiler -> Other Swift  Flags`, because then I cannot read them from objective-c code.

I have the following set in both my app's main target and the project:

[image]

then, under my app's second target (my Today Extension),  I set IS_MAIN=0.

[image]

However,  when I run this code:

```
#if IS_MAIN
    print("main: true")
#else
    print("main: false")
#endif
```

It never prints the correct one.

How can I add this preprocessor flag so that it is respected by both my Swift and objective-c files? Right now it works in neither type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want to do. Read [this](https://medium.com/@t.camin/preprocessor-macros-in-swift-d73ac65ac11c) article to understand more about pre processors and swift.

Basically, before Xcode 8, you would have to add the required flag in `Other Swift Flags` in `Build settings`. Add it like this. Note the *"-D" option*

[image]

After Xcode 8, Apple has added another setting called `Active Compilation Conditions` where you can add your pre processor macro *without the "-D" option* and swift will be able to recognize it.

> In both the cases, you do not add the value `=1`. You just mention the flag in one configuration and do not mention the flag in another and your `#if` condition will work

Comment: yep, adding it under Active Compilation Conditions and NOT including the =1 was indeed correct. I was under the assumption that my objective-c code could not pick up this info since it said "Swift compiler", but apparently I was incorrect

Answer (score 8):

You need to set swift custom flags to access the pre-macro processors in swift.

If you don't want to set preprocessor macro for multiple architectures, then you can just use like this.
[image]

For example here, I have GEO=1 in my debug scheme with value 1.

To access in Objective C there is no problem, but to access in swift you need to expose it in the swift other flags like this.

In your case, you need to add -DIS_MAIN in the custom flag.

I hope it helps!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add under `Active Compilation Conditions` as,

[image]