# How to define DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

I use Xcode 11 and need to replicate this compiler command:

```
cc -g -Wall -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic \
    -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES -c -o example.o example.c
```

Adding `OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES` as a user defined macro with no value to the Build Settings doesn't help. Also defining it in the source fails by telling me it already got defined by Xcode via the command line. Despite setting a few suspicious flags to `No`, it seems Xcode keeps executing `#define OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES 1`. How can I disable that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Xcode works but I see two points.

In the image you post you ask for a define like `DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES`, but in the command line you show it is `OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES`. Which one you want to define? (Note the first `D` in the image: it isn't in the command line.)

With the first `D` the command line parameter would be:

```
-DDOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES
```

(The `-D` is to *define*, the rest is what is defined.)

Normally that define should be made in the *preprocessor* options, not the compiler. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624896/adding-pre-processor-macros-in-xcode-10/56626095) although I don't know if the example is outdated. (There should be an option somewhere to set preprocessor defines though.)

If Xcode, no matter what, defines that as `1`, you can redefine it whenever you need it:

```
#ifdef OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES
#undef OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES
#define OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES
#endif
```

(Or `DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES`.)

That will get rid of the `1`.

You have more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56626095/980129).